# Scala/Spark save texts in program without save to files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code will save `val: s` into `result.txt`
And then read the file again
I want to know is there a method My code can run directly without save to another file and read it back.

I user `val textFile = sc.parallelize(s)`

But the next part would have error: `value contains is not a member of char`

```
import java.io._
val s = (R.capture("lines"))

resultPath = /home/user
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(f"$resultPath%s/result.txt"))
pw.write(s)
pw.close
//val textFile = sc.textFile(f"$resultPath%s/result.txt") old method:save into a file and read it back
val textFile = sc.parallelize(s)    


val rows = textFile.map { line =>
  !(line contains "[, 1]")
  val fields = line.split("[^\\d.]+")
  ((fields(0), fields(1).toDouble))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say the problem you are having is that the variable s is a **String** data type and you are doing a parallelize on a String instead of a collection. So when you run the map function it is iterating over each character in the String.

Comment: Thank you!  I found a method  ````val textFile = sc.parallelize(s.split("\n"))    ````